# How can I list each item from list in a cell in csv?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to add each item from a list in a cell of CSV, items are strings but when I export it, each letter of the string is in a different cell, instead of the complete string in a different cell.

This is my current code:

```
import csv
list_names = ['1. Bar 61 Restaurant', '2. Companero', '3. 28 Church Row', '4. Miss Tapas', '5. The Little Taperia', '6. Twist', '7. Volare']

file_to_output = open("newfile.csv", "w", newline="")
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=",")
for item in list_names:
    csv_writer.writerows([item,])

file_to_output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the for loop do it directly.

```
file_to_output = open("newfile.csv", "w", newline="") 
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=",") 
csv_writer.writerows([list_names,])

file_to_output.close()
```

Comment: To stick with a loop approach to make adaptations to the names or something like that, use a list comprehension instead of the for loop: `csv_writer.writerow([name for name in list_names])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas module

```
import pandas as pd
list_names = ['1. Bar 61 Restaurant', '2. Companero', '3. 28 Church Row', '4. Miss Tapas', '5. The Little Taperia', '6. Twist', '7. Volare']

df = pd.DataFrame(list_name, columns=some_column_name)
df.to_csv("path", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use writerow:

```
import csv
list_names = ['1. Bar 61 Restaurant', '2. Companero', '3. 28 Church Row', '4. Miss Tapas', '5. The Little Taperia',
              '6. Twist', '7. Volare']

file_to_output = open("newfile.csv", "w", newline="")
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output, delimiter=",")
for item in list_names: csv_writer.writerow([item])

file_to_output.close()
```